# Hibernate XML mapping

Tags: xml, hibernate

I want to save data from xml file to db. This is xml example:

```
<Stock>
    <Code>7052</Code>
    <Name>PADINI</Name>
    <StockDailyRecords>
        <PriceOpen>1.2</PriceOpen>
        <PriceChange>1.1</PriceChange>
        <PriceClose>10.0</PriceClose>
        <Volume>3000000L</Volume>
    </StockDailyRecords>
    <StockDailyRecords>
        <PriceOpen>1.3</PriceOpen>
        <PriceChange>1.2</PriceChange>
        <PriceClose>11.0</PriceClose>
        <Volume>5000000L</Volume>
    </StockDailyRecords>
</Stock>
```

I want to save data into two tables with one-to-many table relationship in Hibernate, via XML mapping file (hbm):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 26 April 2011 11:37:37 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="Stock" table="STOCK" node="Stock">
        <id name="stockId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="STOCK_ID" />
            <generator class="sequence" />
        </id>
        <property name="stockCode" type="string" node="Code">
            <column name="STOCK_CODE" length="10" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="stockName" type="string" node="Name">
            <column name="STOCK_NAME" length="20" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="stockDailyRecords" table="STOCK_DAILY_RECORD" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="STOCK_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many entity-name="StockDailyRecord" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping> 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 26 April 2011 11:37:37 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="StockDailyRecord" table="STOCK_DAILY_RECORD" node="StockDailyRecords">
        <id name="recordId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="RECORD_ID" />
            <generator class="sequence" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="stock" fetch="select" entity-name="Stock">
            <column name="STOCK_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="priceOpen" type="java.lang.Float" node="PriceOpen">
            <column name="PRICE_OPEN" precision="6" />
        </property>
        <property name="priceClose" type="java.lang.Float" node="PriceClose">
            <column name="PRICE_CLOSE" precision="6" />
        </property>
        <property name="priceChange" type="java.lang.Float" node="PriceChange">
            <column name="PRICE_CHANGE" precision="6" />
        </property>
        <property name="volume" type="java.lang.Long" node="Volume">
            <column name="VOLUME" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is my implementation code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {

        InputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\log\\UserData.xml");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        org.dom4j.Document document = new SAXReader().read(input);
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Session dom4jSession = session.getSession(EntityMode.DOM4J);

        dom4jSession.save(document.getRootElement());

        System.out.println("Done");

        dom4jSession.flush();

        transaction.commit();

        session.close();
    }
```

But it save data only to 'STOCK' table. Table 'STOCK_DAILY_RECORD' is empty. How can I solve this problem?

Solve!)

Stock.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 26 April 2011 11:37:37 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="Stock" table="STOCK" node="Stock">
        <id name="stockId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="STOCK_ID" />
            <generator class="sequence" />
        </id>
        <property name="stockCode" type="string" node="Code">
            <column name="STOCK_CODE" length="10" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="stockName" type="string" node="Name">
            <column name="STOCK_NAME" length="20" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="stockDailyRecords" node="." cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="STOCK_IDD" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many entity-name="StockDailyRecord" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

StockDailyRecord.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 26 April 2011 11:37:37 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="Stock" table="STOCK" node="Stock">
        <id name="stockId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="STOCK_ID" />
            <generator class="sequence" />
        </id>
        <property name="stockCode" type="string" node="Code">
            <column name="STOCK_CODE" length="10" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="stockName" type="string" node="Name">
            <column name="STOCK_NAME" length="20" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="stockDailyRecords" node="." cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="STOCK_IDD" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many entity-name="StockDailyRecord" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {

        InputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\log\\UserData.xml");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        org.dom4j.Document document = new SAXReader().read(input);
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Session dom4jSession = session.getSession(EntityMode.DOM4J);

        dom4jSession.save(document.getRootElement());

        System.out.println("Done");

        dom4jSession.flush();

        transaction.commit();

        session.close();
    }
```